# Conditional statement inside for loop stats.linregress

Tags: python

I am relatively new to python, so still learning effective loop coding.

I have worked on creating a for loop, meant to iterate through numeric variables in a data set. The loop (as written) graphs a plot and provides bivariate statistics on all the numeric variables in my dataset. But there are over 100 variables in the data set so iterating through all combinations is both extremely taxing and unnecessary.

What I am trying to figure out now is what code I can insert into this loop (and where) which will allow me to set a threshold on r (being the r in stats.linregress). The purpose is to alleviate the code iterating through every combination of numeric variables in the data set and instead limit the iterations to variable combinations with a set r value (setting it at a value that has significance), thus skipping unnecessary iterations of combinations.
I thought a basic if/else would work, but it keeps breaking on me or plotting an empty graph.

code I am using:

```
list_of_checked_variables= []
for column_a in numeric_variable_list:
    for column_b in numeric_variable_list:
        list_of_checked_variables.append(column_a)
        if column_b not in list_of_checked_variables:
            correlation_plot = sns.regplot(x=df[column_a], y=df[column_b])
            sns.despine(top=True, right=True)
            # regression line
            m, b, r, p, err = stats.linregress(df[column_a], df[column_b])
            # Add formula, r^2, and p-value to the graph
            textstr= 'y  = ' + str(round(m, 2)) + 'x + ' + str(round(b, 2)) + '\n'
            textstr += 'r2 = ' + str(round(r**2, 4)) + '\n'
            textstr += 'p  = ' + str(round(p, 4))
            plt.text(0.15, 0.70, textstr, fontsize=12, transform=plt.gcf().transFigure)
            plt.show(correlation_plot)
            plt.close()
        else:
            continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Looping many times is expensive (i.e. slow and uses a lot of memory) in Python because, unlike C++, everything is an object. At every iteration in the loop, Python makes a new object. List/dictionary comprehensions and generator expressions help with this because they are optimized at the C level, so use them wherever you can. (f-strings are also an optimized feature in Python 3.x, so you should try to use those where you can as well; I think they're more readable.)

For combinations- and permutations-type problems, I would use the built-in `itertools` module.

```py
import itertools
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

import seaborn as sns

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # ...get your numeric_variable_list
    
    # Set r-threshold
    rthresh = 0.95  # Example

    # Get tuple of combos
    combos = itertools.combinations(numeric_variable_list, 2)

    # Dictionary comprehension
    regstats = {c:stats.linregress(c[0], c[1]) for c in combos}
    regstats = {k:v for (k,v) in regstats.items() if v[2] >= rthresh}

    for c, stat in regstats.items():
        m, b, r, p, err = stat
        
        // Create plots
        correlation_plot = sns.regplot(c[0], c[1])
        sns.despine(top=True, right=True)
        
        # Make your text
        textstr = f"y = {m:.2f}x + {b:.2f}\n"
        textstr += f"r2 = {r**2:.4f}\n"
        textstr += f"p = {p:.4f}"
        
        plt.text(
            0.15, 
            0.70, 
            textstr, 
            fontsize=12, 
            transform=plt.gcf().transFigure
        )
        
        plt.show(correlation_plot)
```

These are my first suggestions. There may be even more you can do improve things, but this should work well. One other thing you may want to research is to automatically `plt.save` your graphs, especially if there are hundreds, rather than going through each and manually saving them individually.

If specific errors pop up, let me know. An `if/else` should work in theory. There may be something hiding in your `numeric_variable_list`, but I can't debug it without knowing the exact error message you're getting.